# Counting the number of job orders per company

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to write a query that returns the name of the company, and the number of the particular Job Orders that company owns.

Right now my query is like this:

```
SELECT c.name, cj.joborder_id
FROM company c, joborder jo, candidate_joborder cj
WHERE c.company_id=jo.company_id
AND jo.joborder_id=cj.joborder_id
AND jo.status = 'Active'
AND cj.status=700;
```

This returns the following table:

```
Name | Job Order ID
X    | 1874
Y    | 2003
Y    | 2003
Z    | 2001
```

What I want is:

```
Name | Count
X    | 1
Y    | 2
Z    | 1
```

Can someone help me with this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query you want is the following:

```
SELECT c.name,
       count(cj.joborder_id)
FROM company c,
     joborder jo,
     candidate_joborder cj
WHERE c.company_id=jo.company_id
  AND jo.joborder_id=cj.joborder_id
  AND jo.status = 'Active'
  AND cj.status=700
GROUP BY c.name;
```

I'd suggest the following references for SQL aggregation and specifically group by and count:

- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fSH1jpV2nNs
- http://www.w3resource.com/sql/aggregate-functions/count-with-group-by.php

Comment: Thanks. I will use them as a future reference.

Answer (score 2):

use `COUNT()` and `GROUP BY` clause,

```
SELECT c.name, COUNT(cj.joborder_id) TotalCount
FROM   company c, joborder jo, candidate_joborder cj
WHERE  c.company_id=jo.company_id
       AND jo.joborder_id=cj.joborder_id
       AND jo.status = 'Active'
       AND cj.status=700
GROUP BY c.name
```

using `ANSI JOIN`

```
SELECT  c.name, 
        COUNT(cj.joborder_id) TotalCount
FROM    company c
        INNER JOIN joborder jo
            ON c.company_id = jo.company_id
        INNER JOIN candidate_joborder cj
            ON jo.joborder_id = cj.joborder_id
WHERE   jo.status = 'Active' AND 
        cj.status=700
GROUP   BY c.name
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT(c.name), COUNT(cj.joborder_id)
FROM company c, joborder jo, candidate_joborder cj
WHERE c.company_id=jo.company_id
AND jo.joborder_id=cj.joborder_id
AND jo.status = 'Active'
AND cj.status=700
GROUP BY c.name
```

Comment: When you use group by, distinct is not needed.

Comment: True, not strictly needed. If you have an index on `c.name`, it's irrelevant. If not, you'd expect `DISTINCT(c.name)` to perform better.